# Recommended paper type and thickness for recipe cards

Tags: paper

I'm in the process of designing some recipe cards for a client. There are two components of the cards.

(1) Index Tabs

[image: Index Tabs]

(2) Recipe Cards

[image: Recipe Cards]

It's important that the end user can write on both sides of the recipe cards.

What thickness and paper type would you recommend for (1) Index Tabs, and (2) Recipe Cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's important that the end user can write on both sides of the recipe cards.

I would not do that normally, because it is contradictory. In a recipe card you want them to stay the cleanest they can, so a UV coating could be on at least one side.

If you can write on it that means that the dirt can also be on it.

But I feel you are not printing any recipe at all, just a template so the user can write their own recipes, right?

In that case it does not matter. Just go for a nice thick paper.

The limitation is on the printing process. If it is sheeted offset ask the printer for the thickest they can print.

If you are using silk printing, get the thickest you can that suits the budget.

Just buy some samples and play with them.

If the paper has too much texture they can be hard to print, but probably the cracked print is a nice touch.

One option, that can be written on and stays somehow clean is **synthetic paper**. This is water proof. Ask your printer about it.

Another commonly used board for this is SBS (bleached sulphate board), they can have 2 coated sides or just one. It has a good rigidity vs the thickness.

Answer (score 1):

Opinionated answer: I would use the same thickness for both card types, the different shape of the card should be enough to separate them. Go with 300g/m².